# Turn off blue "1" symbol next to texts on Samsung Galaxy S7

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s7, dual-sim, app-icons

I just recently got a Samsung Galaxy S7.

As shown in the pictures, there is a blue 1 symbol next to all of my texts. I only found one forum online that said this was due to the "dual sim". However there were no comments as to how to turn it off. Does anyone know?

Also, do anyone know what the symbol means next to the left of mute symbol on the top part of the screen? I tried to indicate it with blue

[image]

Comment: N stands for (activated) NFC.

Comment: From the shape of the symbol, I'd guess it tells you through which sim card the text was sent/received. IIRC the S7 has two sim slots, so an indicator for which sim card is used makes sense.

Comment: Do you know if there is anyway to stop it from showing this symbol? With the dual sim, you can have a sim in one slot, and a micro SD in the other. 

Even after removing the micro SD (so there is only one sim in the tray) the symbol still pops up

Comment: Symbol in statusbar is for NFC turn it of to hide symbol. And "1" shows from which sim card message is sent/recived and else. Since you have dual sim phone i doubt it can be rwmoved.

Comment: If this symbol is shown even with only one sim installed, it's possible (likely even?) that they didn't implement the ability to disable it. This may be an oversight or a decision. I don't have an S7 at hand, so I can't poke around its settings, but using an alternative messaging app may get rid of it. [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=sms%20app) has several messaging apps, good and otherwise. If you don't want to use another app, and no one knows how to disable this indicator, you may simply have to live with it.

Comment: Try this worked for my Samsung J7.
http://www.samsung.com/sa_en/support/skp/faq/1072114